# Get the date when the row was inserted MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to get a datetime when the row was created? Is it stored anywhere? I just forgot to add a column which tells when the row was inserted, and lots of rows have been inserted and I don't know when they were inserted... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to achieve that. `MySQL` doesn't store a `timestamp` of row creation, that's why you always have to create a column to do that, along with `ON UPDATE` clause which will update the column every time the row is updated

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need a column to record that, it's not stored in the system otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get timestamp when the row was created unless you add a field that is populated with system time or has a [default value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL to create a column in table foo called create_ts.
It also sets all the records to have the field set to the time when you ran the ALTER TABLE command.

ALTER TABLE foo ADD create_ts DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;