# How to find last 30 days records form table in MariaDB if don't have any date column in the table

Tags: mariadb

There is not any date column in table and i want to fetch the records which are created in last 30 days.

I have tried to find the table properties and history but found no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does MariaDB store a timestamp when a given row is inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285473/does-mariadb-store-a-timestamp-when-a-given-row-is-inserted)

Comment: Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614946/get-the-date-when-the-row-was-inserted-mysql